# What can affect my GPS?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have recently started experiencing some very severe "roaming" in my Pokémon Go, over the past couple of days. At work, I like to leave my app open, as the GPS likes to "wobble" a bit (my avatar will generally just wander around the block/across the street), so I can get some free k's in over the course of the day... up to 5km on a good day.

However, over the past couple of days, this has gone to the absolute extreme. When in the office, my avatar will now take up residence halfway across town - nowhere near where my office is located. The avatar doesn't walk around when in this location, but occasionally, it will immediately jump between there, and my actual location, instantly. The distance between the Avatar's location, and my physical location is ~8km (~5 miles).

I work on the top floor of a 2 storey building, near the road, so I can't see anything about the building itself causing this, but this only happens when I'm at work. Even when I exit the building, the GPS will correct itself... but like I said, I have *never* experienced anything this extreme before, over several months.

**What could be causing this?**

[Here is a link to a video showing the jump](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DXoEvlQvez8iXeG7SAfrVtLUNZr-Q2X0)

---

Post note; I am the only one with access to my account, I do not have Pokémon Go on any other devices (I don't even own a Pokémon Go Plus), and the location that my avatar likes to jump to is near the beach - there are no large structures or any kind of radio tower in that area.

Comment: I just figured out the distance between the two spots... ~8k/5miles

Comment: Open google maps or the apple equivalent. Does the GPS wander in that too?

Comment: @Studoku Just checked it, and yeah. The Avatar is going off the GPS's actual location